# How to match "4.4" from `uname -r`?

Tags: bash, shell, regular-expression, test

Pseudocode

```
[ `uname -r` =~ ^4\.4.*$ ] && echo "yes"
```

which is, however, unsuccessful in all cases. 
The `uname -r` command gives things like `4.6.0-040600-generic` as an output.

Comment: I'm assuming you have some other systems that return 4.4.something?

Comment: manual page is good place to start. Manual page for `[` (`test`) does not have `~=` operator. It is bash built-in `[[`, which accepts `~=` operator.

Comment: also, "matching" on `.*$` is superfluous -- just stop at "^4\.4\.". Otherwise you're saying "match start-of-line, 4, period, 4, (anything), end-of-line" - and you don't care what the (anything) is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash operator `[` may not be what you are looking for; however, `[[` does support `=~`. Try this:

```
[[ $(uname -r) =~ ^4\.4 ]] && echo yes
```

Comment: you beat me by seconds. :)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your use case (e.g.testing multiple values), you might find the "case" syntax a better fit.

```
case $(uname -r) in
   4.4*) echo 4.4 based kernel found ;;
  3.10*) echo 3.10 based kernel found ;;
      *) echo unknown kernel found
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

use `[[` :

```
ver=$(cut -d. -f1-2 <(uname -r))
[[ $ver =~ 3.2 ]] && echo "y"
```

OR use `[`:

```
ver=$(cut -d. -f1-2 <(uname -r))
[ $ver == 3.2 ] && echo "y"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
case $(uname -r) in (4.4.*) echo yes;; esac
```